# Naming: the thing(s) something else depends on?

Tags: naming

I have a nomenclature question.
Suppose you have a drop down selection whose choices depend on the value of a different selection.  For example, the values in a drop down listing car models would depend on the selected make.

While trying to document an algorithm and when naming variables I can't think of what to call the thing that the dependent properties depend on.  It feels like it should be obvious, but it's not coming to me.  Online searches have produced too many unhelpful hits.
Is there a good term for this, or must I stick with "the property that the dependent property depends on"?

Comment: I don't think there's a "standard" if that's what you're asking.  In the car example, the first value would be Make and the second would be Model.  The domain knowledge indicates that Model is based on Make, but there's no specific nomenclature to identify that in its name alone.  For variable naming, I'd argue that changing Model's name because it has a relationship to Make would be incorrect, since Model is already a well-known and established name in that domain.

Comment: @David, Yes, model would still be named model in some parts of the code. But then in a generic function used for several such properties, it would not be right to use "model".  When it came time to document the algorithm I was stumped.

Comment: Isn't the proper name for "that on which something depends" the "dependee"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Parent Property, Master Property, or Control Property?

Comment: Master or control would work. Perhaps not perfect, but better than what I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"requirements" or "prerequisites" might be suitable words to convey the meaning you expressed.